# Current limiting AC

Tags: ac, current-limiting, etching

I am currently experimenting with electrolytic marking. I use a DC bench supply with a current dial so I can drive the reaction with a constant current to keep the marking steady and as a plus keep it safe against short circuits!

But I read you can get different results if you use AC ( I guess its etching and anodizing perhaps? ) My worry though is that it is uncontrolled, is there a device or circuit that would let me control or at least limit the current of an AC supply? I can not see this in normal AC bench supplies, variacs? usually they appear to use a fuse).

Comment: What sort of AC voltage do you need?  Are you using an AC transformer?  I'd think 12 / 24 VAc would be pretty safe.  The current limit looks harder. (if it's not a simple voltage drop with an R or C.)

Answer (score 1):

If one wants AC current limit one uses Ballast choke in series..try if it could help you to have AC itching.
vtingole